# What is the largest possible size of a root partition?

Tags: partitioning, root

I know that using a boot-able partition over 123 GB is not good but what is the max root size allowable? is there a limit?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with a bootable partition over 123GB (where would this limit come from?). There are various limits with some older hardware; Ubuntu itself has no problem (for anything that will fit on a hard disk in the next few years, at least).

Comment: The limit is only limited by the hardware manufacturer.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the filesystem used for `/`.

Provided your 'initramfs' can use that filesystem (modules available at boot time), it all depends on which you chose.

- [Ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3): max 16 TiB
- [Ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4): max 1 EiB
- [XFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS): max 16 EiB
- *fs: *you get the point*

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the filesystem. The maximum size of a volume of a particular filesystem is given in the [Limits section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) of the appropriate Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

In mentioning 123 GB, I think you are referring to the 28 bit limitation on the LBA (Logical Block Address) that can pass over standard IDE equipment. Please see http://www.48bitlba.com/overview.htm It's several years old.

It mentions that the next following limit is at 2 TiB, because stored LBA's can only hold 32 bits in basic and extended partitions.

To get around the first limit you should be careful about the hardware you install. Presumably current large disks have 48 bit LBA support and I assume current motherboards will support them. Refer to ATA-6.

To get beyond the 2TiB limit you should format your disk with GPT rather than the old-fashioned MBR based primary and extended partitions. That allows addressing disk space to 2^73 bytes without changing the current disk sector size.

Beyond that pick your file system for maximum size, but with an eye toward the features and performance you need for your application(s).